# stock management

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables, `INWARDS` and `OUTWARDS`. I have to show total inwards and total outwards on each date for every different stock as well as the balance of stocks left on that date. I don't need to group by any date, I just want to have to total number of stocks in my inventory.

i have written my query as follows:

```
SELECT
    I.Date as'Date',
    P.ResourceName as 'Item Name',
    P.ResourceRate as'Rate',
    i.Qty as Inwards Quantity',
    (   select qty
        from Outwards_master
        where I.Date=S.Date and I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
    ) as 'Outwards Quantity',
    (   select (sum(i.qty)-sum(S.Qty))
        from Inwards_Master
            inner join Outwards_Master
            on i.Nameofitem=S.Nameofitem
    ) as 'Balance'
From Resource_Master P, Inwards_Master I, Outwards_Master S
WHERE (I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName) and P.TenderCode = 1
```

This query gives me an error. What is the problem?

the error is:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Inwards_Master.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What error does the query return?

Comment: I suggest you put a bit of effort in to formatting your question so that others will feel encouraged to put effort in to answering it.

Comment: i have formatted my answer @MarkD . can u plz help me now?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't address your problem, I was away. The thing is you will almost always get a lightning quick solution when you post a visually clear problem with as much details about your problem and expectation as possible. Glad you came right :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a guess based on your query that you want something like this:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date, 
  P.ResourceName as ItemName,
  P.ResourceRate as Rate,
  i.Qty as InwardsQuantity,
  s.qty as OutwardsQuantity,
  i.qty-S.Qty as Balance,
  O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P
  ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
INNER JOIN Inwards_Master I
  ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName
INNER JOIN Outwards_Master S 
  ON I.Date=S.Date 
  AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode=1
```

If you want to show all items, then you might want to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date, 
  P.ResourceName as ItemName,
  P.ResourceRate as Rate,
  i.Qty as InwardsQuantity,
  s.qty as OutwardsQuantity,
  i.qty-S.Qty as Balance,
  O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P
  ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
LEFT JOIN Inwards_Master I
  ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName
LEFT JOIN Outwards_Master S 
  ON I.Date=S.Date 
  AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode=1
```

Edit #1, Based on your comments, I cannot quite tell what the issue is but you can try getting the total quantity in a subquery:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date, 
  P.ResourceName as ItemName,
  P.ResourceRate as Rate,
  i.TotalInQty as InwardsQuantity,
  s.TotalOutQty as OutwardsQuantity,
  i.TotalInQty-S.TotalOutQty as Balance,
  O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P
  ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
LEFT JOIN
(
  select sum(i.Qty) TotalInQty, Nameofitem
  from Inwards_Master I
  group by Nameofitem
) I
  ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName
LEFT JOIN
(
  select sum(s.qty) TotalOutQty, Nameofitem
  from Outwards_Master S 
  group by s.Nameofitem
) S
  ON I.Date=S.Date 
  AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode=1
```

Comment: yes i exactly want this but this query shows me only rows that are common in INWARDS and OUTWARDS, i want all the items that were inwarded even if they were not outwarded, because the stocks contains all the stocks that are available with us.

can u plz help with this??

Comment: @kunaljangade see my edit, you might want a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: no its still not working. it shows balance as NULL in the available stocks when it needs to show the number of available stocks

Comment: see it shows me balance only on stocks which were outwarded but it should also show values of stocks that were not outwarded bcoz they are still in stock as they were inwarded

Comment: @kunaljangade can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d46c/3) with your tables and some sample data?

Comment: sry i don't know how to create sql fiddle.

Comment: see what i did helped me a bit i changed your code, but i have many items in outwards and i want to have balance of every item, this query works great for only 1 item in outwards table can u help me for multiple items in outwards table???

Comment: @bluefeet "see i am sending you an image of my tables here the output of our query is as below the 1st is inwards table 2nd is outwards and the final is o/p of our query. here the balance is null even if the inwards table has items in it, please can u help me for this (http://i.stack.imgur.com/089tM.png)" [from the OP]

Comment: @bluefeet itis giving me an error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Column 'Inwards_Master.Nameofitem' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @kunaljangade I don't know why you would be getting that error, can you create your table structures and some sample data in a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3). Here is a [version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61e51/1) that already has tables and queries, just edit it with your tables/data in the left panel and post the link here.